# Pointers casting in C "on the fly"

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I have the following question:

Is it possible to cast pointer "on the fly", without additional variable assignment? Let's see some example:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t             TimeSlot;
    uint8_t             TimeTick; 
}Menager_t;


void SomeFunction(void* vp)
{

(Menager_t *)vp->TimeSlot = 0; //Error, request for member 'TimeSlot' 
                               //in something not a structure or union
}
```

So, this can be solved by assign void pointer to temporary pointer inside of function, like this:

```
void SomeFunction(void* vp)
{

Menager_t *temp = vp; 
temp->TimeSlot = 0;

}
```

But i must say that this solution does not satisfy me and looks dirty form me (omitting fact of 128 bytes RAM memory on uC I'm programming) and furthermore I remember that i was doing such things in past...

I'm asking You guys kindly for help in that :)
Regards!

PS: GCC 4.7.2 in use

Comment: You have your answer below but I have to say that most functions do a lot more than access one structure element. So it reads a lot better to assign a new pointer of the correct type at the start of the function.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the suggestion. However, I'm working on small embedded device end each auto-variable is a high cost for me right now. But on PC i guess You are totally right!

Comment: In most circumstances, the compiler will optimize that variable out anyway (a cast from `void *` to `struct *` is a no-op).

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to add some parenthesis.

```
((Menager_t *)vp)->TimeSlot = 0;
```

`->` binds more strongly that `(cast)` operator, therefore `vp->TimeSlot` is evaluated first.

Answer (score 1):

`->` has higher precendence than the cast (see, e.g., here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), so the compiler tries to access `TimeSlot` on a `void *`. Add parentheses to make the cast happen first:

```
((Menager_t *)vp)->TimeSlot = 0;
```